# tweetinvi not being able to retrieve timeline tweets and storing into arraylist

Tags: c#, twitter, arraylist, visual-studio-2015, tweetinvi

I am able to connect into twitter with my credentials and also able to retrieve the timeline tweets and displaying into debug console, but i cant seem to be able to store the timeline tweets into my Arraylist as they give me a Code : 408
Error documentation description : Twitter was not able to perform your query within the Timeout limit of 10000 ms and a null pointer.

public static IEnumerable testAuthenticatedUser()
        {

```
        var timelineTweets = default(IEnumerable<ITweet>);
        Auth.SetUserCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret, access_token, access_token_secret);
        TweetinviEvents.QueryBeforeExecute += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(args.QueryURL);
        };
        var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
        var latestException = ExceptionHandler.GetLastException();
        Debug.WriteLine(latestException);
        timelineTweets = authenticatedUser.GetUserTimeline();

        latestException = ExceptionHandler.GetLastException();
        Debug.WriteLine(latestException);

        ArrayList timeLineList = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
                 foreach (var tweet in timelineTweets)
            {

            Debug.WriteLine(tweet.Text);
            timeLineList.Add(tweet.Text);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        int countTimeLineList = timeLineList.Count;
        Debug.WriteLine("Array List Count: " + countTimeLineList);
        return timelineTweets;
    }
```

Comment: do you mind to share full source code through Dropbox or Google Drive ? it seems that twitter block your request for Timeout limit

Comment: sure! 

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r2tp4h5g2cqcrrk/AAD_WkBtBiyBlt8ztjYr-wcpa?dl=0

Comment: Which part of this code is throwing the 408 exception?

Comment: It's after  ArrayList timeLineList = new ArrayList(); this line